# Conditional update, depending on field matched-Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, if-statement, mongodb-query, conditional-statements

I have simple collection like this:

```
db.people.insert( 
    [
        {
        name:"John",
        sex:"M"
        },
        {
        name:"Susanne",
        sex:"W"
        },
        {
        name:"Kate",
        sex:"W"
        }
])
```

On the basis of sex field I would like to create other field Sex2:

```
case
when sex:"M" then sex2:"Man"
when sex:"W" then sex2:"Women"
```

any tips how I can manage it with .update function?

Comment: My version of mongodb is 3.2.22

Comment: Use the same concept as the marked duplicate where your cursor follows `var cursor = db.people.aggregate([ 
    { "$project":  { 
        "sex2": { "$cond": [ { "$eq": ["$sex", "W"] }, "Women", "Men" ] } 
    }}
])`